# Avoiding overhead when nothing is subscribed *to a pipeline*

Tags: ros, master, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that [publish doesn't do anything if nothing is subscribed to a node.](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#publish.28.29_behavior_and_queueing)

[A while back, you guys helped me](http://answers.ros.org/question/32718/avoiding-overhead-when-nothing-subscribed/)  avoid work in my own callbacks if nothing is subscribed to my node.

But what about the case of pipelines? Let's say I have nodes (a, b, c, and d), each one feeding the next. All I really care about is the output of d (except for debugging). If I write the nodes, I can subscribe and unsubscribe to the input, thus avoiding the work of the pipeline. However, with nodes I didn't write, this is likely not the case, and so I only avoid the work done by the last node, since c still has the subscriber d.

Is there any work toward this kind of efficiency of a whole pipeline? Perhaps some kind of pipeline API in the works that can tell a node **not** to execute a callback even if it has a subscriber because the output *of the pipeline* isn't being subscribed to?

**EDIT**

For clarity, let me elaborate a bit more and give an example.

Let's say I have a kinect and all its nodelets producing a point cloud.  I also use the [pcl_nodelets](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros?distro=jade#ROS_nodelets). The raw point cloud output goes to a cropbox nodelet. The cropbox feeds a voxelgrid nodelet, and the voxelgrid filter feeds a planar segmentation nodelet. I write a node that uses the model parameters from the plane.

kinect -> cropbox -> voxelgrid -> segmentation -> user_application

My user_application nodelet does not always need the model parameters. In the user_application node, I could subscribe and unsubscribe from the model parameters.  If the segmentation nodelet is well written, it won't do any work upon recieving a point cloud from the voxelgrid filter since no one is subscribed.

However, the voxelgrid *will* still do work since it still has a subscriber, namely the segmentation nodelet. Likewise, the cropbox still processes for the voxelgrid. I'm interested in avoiding the work that these other nodelets are doing.

It's possible to write the node[let]s so that they subscribe and unsubscribe in each step of the pipeline, so that when my user_application node subscribes to the segmentation node, it causes a chain reaction where the segmentation node then subscribes to the voxelgrid nodelet, the voxelgrid subscribes to the cropbox and so on. Unsubscribe would work the same way. This seems hard to debug, though, as the nodes will not always show as connected in rosnode info nor in the graph gui.

It could also be standard procedure to write node[let]s that will be part of a pipeline with a separate `process` topic/service, so that upon receiving a message on the process topic, the pipeline processing starts or stops. That adds more overhead to get the pipeline running, though. And what if you want to look at the intermediate steps in the pipeline when the pipeline isn't running?

My thought: what if there was a way when launching a node[let] to specify that it was a pipeline node or a pipeline output node. Then, when a node checks to see if there are any subscribers listening (in order to decide whether to do all the work in its callback), it would see that, yes, there are subscribers, but they are pipeline subscribers, and the output of the pipeline isn't being used, so don't do any work. Rostopic echo would still count as a normal node and would cause work to be done.

It might be best to just write the whole thing as one node if I'm really that concerned about efficiency, but I really like the reusability and distributed model of the nodes.

I can surely open up an enhancement request, but I figured this was more of a general is-anybody-else-having-this-problem or a what-if than a concrete enhancement proposal. It might be bad practice anyway. Anyway, I'm unsure if it's actually possible and I'm unsure of which package it should live in. Let me know of a good place to put this and I'll definitely put it there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216228/avoiding-overhead-when-nothing-is-subscribed-*to-a-pipeline*/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-08-20**:
Interesting. It makes more sense to me to be implemented in lower level (maybe `rostopic` and equivalent) to optionally return if there's no subscribers (pretty much like [your reference](http://answers.ros.org/question/32718/avoiding-overhead-when-nothing-subscribed/)).

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-08-20**:
Or do you think coordinated behavior (by pipeline) better? Anyway this is enhancement discussion that's better opened at somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik this does not exist in ROS and I would have suggested to unsubscribe on demand. As you describe this, you want to uphold the subscription to see this in the node graph, but only stop processing internally. As nodes do not have any way to figure this out, you will need something external.

Given that any pipeline node cannot know anything about the configuration and where the exit subscribers are, you will have to either setup some kind of manager (for nodelets the nodelet manager could be used) or provide an parallel pipeline mechanism that connects all pipeline nodes and instead of the data only provides the information if things should be computed backwards through the pipeline.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0